# python gae Blocking access to static files on mac or linux but not windows

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'm having an issue converting over to a linux or mac development environment from a windows one. I have tried both linux and max to debug the problem that I'm having.

I have a small gae python project that works locally in windows. But after I moved it over to linux or windows i'm getting an error that says

```
Blocking access to static files "/home/name/WSR/src/__init__.py"
```

Here is a copy of my app.yaml file

```
application: service-app 
version: 3
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /common
  static_dir: common

- url: /WSR
  static_dir: WSR

- url: /admin/.*
  script: WSR.admin.main.app

- url: /admin
  script: WSR.admin.main.app

- url: /requestService
  script: WSR.com.main.app

- url: /submitInquiry
  script: WSR.com.main.app

- url: /test
  script: WSR.com.test.app

- url: /.*
  script: WSR.com.main.app  

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

i believe that the problem is coming from

```
- url: /WSR
  static_dir: WSR
```

i have a bunch of python code / html code / javascript and css under here.

Comment: Read the GAE documentation on [static files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles). You've defined that entire directory to be static.

Comment: I did read the documentation on static files. I've split this out so that only css / js and html files are in the static dir. but I want to know why the functionality is different in a window vs a mac / linux development environment.

Comment: It shouldn't work.  Either your app.yaml isn't exactly the same, or perhaps there's a bug in the Windows version of the SDK.

Comment: i moved all my back end stuff out of the static dir and everything is working. ya it looks like a strange windows bug..